# Programmatically populate an array with images to be animated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, arrays, animation

I have a folder (called "beeanim") of 50 images in my resources folder. I want to fill an array with these images and then run an animation with the images. Each image is named `bee1`, `bee2`.........`bee50`.

When i go to run the app in xcode i get an error in the console saying:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`

This makes me believe that i might not be referencing the filename correctly but i don't know how else to do it than i already have. I'd appreciate any help. This is my code:

```
-(void) createBeeImage {

    NSString *fileName; 
    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 51; i++) {
        fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"beeanim/bee%d.png", i];
        [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
    }
    UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                             CGRectMake(215, 250, 174, 80)];
    imgView.animationImages = imageArray;
    imgView.animationDuration = 2;
    imgView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView startAnimating];


}
```

Comment: seems like your code is crashing as you only have 50 images and you are trying to loop for 51 images (as shown in ur code) just change `i<=51` to `1<=50`. It should work now..

Comment: For future reference, the FIRST thing you should do is either use NSLog or NSAssert to make sure what you want to happen is happening, for example, after `fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"beeanim/bee%d.png", i];` I'd put `NSLog(@"Adding image named %@", fileName);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 51; i++)
```

last value of i will be 51, such an image does not exist according to your description, therefore

`[UIImage imageNamed:]` returns nil which cannot be inserted into `NSMutableArray`

Comment: Thanks. That's a stupid error on my part. The `=` sign was purely out of habit. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is bundled with your app already, you do not need the folder name.  Try just:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 51; i++) {
    fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bee%d.png", i];
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:fileName]];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bundled with your app"? Either way, i tried using just `fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"bee%d.png", i];` but to no avail; i get the same error as in my original post

Comment: For future reference, "bundled with the app" means it is included in your project file, therefore when xcode compiles the app binary, those image files are included within the app bundle and can be accessed directly, just by name